# Nginx unable to find libpcre.so.0 after install from source

Tags: nginx

I am building nginx from source on ubuntu 14.04 but after building, when I run nginx I get the following error:

```
/etc/nginx/sbin/nginx: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.0: 
     cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The reason is probably because it is called libpcre.so.3. Is there a package I can install for libpcre0?

Can I configure nginx to use libpcre.so.3 somehow?

Comment: check this: http://chandank.com/webservers/nginx/nginx-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libpcre-so-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the how to compile Nginx with OpenSSL and Pcre-8.36, with custom Username and Group for additional privileges:

```
./configure --with-cc-opt="-I $STATICLIBSSL/include -I/usr/include" \
--with-ld-opt="-L $STATICLIBSSL/lib -Wl,-rpath -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lz" \
--sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx \
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
--pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid \
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
--with-pcre=/lib/libpcre.so.1
--with-http_ssl_module \
--with-http_spdy_module \
--with-file-aio \
--with-ipv6 \
--with-http_gzip_static_module \
--with-http_stub_status_module \
--without-mail_pop3_module \
--without-mail_smtp_module \
--without-mail_imap_module \
--user=nginx \
--group=nginx \
--with-http_spdy_module \
--with-http_auth_request_module \
--with-openssl=/root/openssl/openssl-1.0.2a/libssl.a
--with-zlib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.a
```